# Pass n arguments to a third party function

Tags: python, arguments

I am using a software named iraf, and I have to pass n arguments to a function, something like:

```
iraf.scombine(input=data[0]+'[1,2,3],'+data[1]+'[1,2,3],'+data[2]+'[1,2,3]',output='tmp')
```

where `data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3],...` are file names, so that `filename[1,2,3]` is a value

Is there a way to do that for n arguments, something like

```
iraf.scombine(input=(data[I]+'[1,2,3]' for I in data),output='tmp')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
iraf.scombine(input="[1,2,3],".join(data), output='tmp')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can build the String before call the function. Something like:

```
my_input = "[1,2,3],".join(data)
iraf.scombine(input=my_input, output='tmp')
```

I think it is more organized and clear.

Using the join string method, you put "[1,2,3],", between each element of the list called data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have the following files in the Current working directory

```
vivek@vivekUbuntu:~/Desktop/Study$ ls
CppProgs  JavaScript              NetworkProtcocols  PerlPrograms  Teach Yourself Database Programming With VisualC++.pdf
HTML&XML  networkingConcepts.txt  Perl               PythonProgs
```

Opening the python shell in the linux terminal.

```
vivek@vivekUbuntu:~/Desktop/Study$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> # Trying to populate the data variable
>>> data = os.listdir('.')
>>> data
['JavaScript', 'PerlPrograms', 'HTML&XML', 'CppProgs', 'Perl', 'Teach Yourself Database Programming With VisualC++.pdf', 'NetworkProtcocols', 'networkingConcepts.txt', 'PythonProgs']
>>> # Now input=data[0] + [1,2,3], ... so on will be written as
>>> data[0] + '[1,2,3]'
'JavaScript[1,2,3]'
>>> # So we can use '[1,2,3],'.join like shown below
>>> '[1,2,3],'.join(data) 
'JavaScript[1,2,3],PerlPrograms[1,2,3],HTML&XML[1,2,3],CppProgs[1,2,3],Perl[1,2,3],Teach Yourself Database Programming With VisualC++.pdf[1,2,3],NetworkProtcocols[1,2,3],networkingConcepts.txt[1,2,3],PythonProgs'
>>> (data[i]+'[1,2,3]' for i in data)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb723dbe4>
>>>
```

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for in the output.
So the Parameter input can be populated by the string `'[1,2,3],'.join(data)`